# Remove-if-not with multiple conditions

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to find all files that ends with .jpg, .png or .jpeg.
I write something like this:

```
(defun get-picture (dir)
  (remove-if-not (lambda (item)
           (or (string= ".jpg" (pathname-type item))
               (string= ".png" (pathname-type item))
               (string= ".jpeg" (pathname-type item))))
         (uiop:directory-files dir)))
```

But it doesn't look good to me. For example, when you want to search more. So I write this:

```
(defun search-file (dir file-types)
  (remove-if-not (lambda (item)
           (mapc (lambda (type)
               (string= type (pathname-type item)))
             file-types))
         (uiop:directory-files dir)))
```

But apparently, mapc is not correctly here.
So I'm wondering is there anyway better to do it(besides dolist)?

Comment: the indentation is strange

Comment: Yes, it looks different from my editor. May cause by fira-code.

Comment: Probably a good idea to edit your code here, to make it readable.

Comment: Thank for your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun get-picture-files (d &key
                            (extensions '("jpg" "png" "jpeg"))
                            (test #'string-equal))
  (remove-if (lambda (p)
               (not (member (pathname-type p)
                            extensions
                            :test test)))
             (uiop:directory-files d)))
```

This

- lets you specify the extensions;
- and the test (so "GOO.JPG");
- calls `pathname-type` just once;
- doesn't use `remove-if-not` which is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks you! And why `remove-if-not` is deprecated?

Comment: REMOVE-IF-NOT will definitely not be in the next standards revision. That new revision will be published anytime soon. /s

Comment: @C-Entropy: there is discussion [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Issues/iss345.htm), but I think the underlying thing is that `(remove-if-not f ...)` is `(remove-if (complement f) ...)`.  I'd be really surprised if it ever actually goes away of course.

Comment: Thank you! I will pay attention to use `complement` to replace `remove-if-not`.

Comment: You could add `:key #'pathname-type` and have a predicate over file types

Comment: A function called `keep-if` which produces a list retaining the items which satisfy a predicate is useful. The only problem is that Common Lisp calls it `remove-if-not`, which is a silly  name containing a semantic double negative: removal together with "not".    Re-spelling the double negative with the even more verbose construction `(remove-if (complement f) ...)` is even more wrongheaded, as is the idea that CL should remove that function itself. CL should give it a better name as an alias (similar to the `car` and `first` situation). The old name could be removed eventually.

Comment: @Kaz: I agree, except that `car` is not a better name than `first`: it's a name for a different thing which happens implementationally to be the same thing.  And `keep-if` should be `filter`, of course.  (And all of this depends on taste, except my taste is the right taste ...)

Comment: @tfp Right; I just meant that `car`/`first` set a precedent for the existence of aliases for one function.  `filter` is ambiguous; are we getting what is passing through the filter, or what is retained in the filter? GNU Make has `$(filter ..)`.  The only reason I remember what it does is that GNU Make has `filter-out` also, and so `filter` must be "filter for".

Comment: @Kaz: yes, you're right.  I had thought that `filter` was in R^^n^^RS for some n, but it doesn't seem to be (it's in Racket), and you're right about ambiguity.  In practice I think `keep-if` is a better name (and if I had a vote I would say that `remove-if-not` should stay too on the grounds of simply not breaking things).